# How to delete drawing in OpenLayers 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, drawing, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to create a map that allows a user to draw on it.
The drawing options are implemented from the official docs and do work.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html

I tried to give the user an option to delete his former drawing.
By holding the key "A" you can see the users selection. 
Now this selected drawings should be deleted in the moment the key is released (but nothing happened).

```
var select = new Select();

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    // A
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        map.addInteraction(select);
    }
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();
        selectedFeatures.clear();
        map.removeInteraction(select);
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Since i am missing the reputation to post a comment, i have to post this as answer.
First, `keyCode` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup), nowadays you should just use `event.key`, which also makes the code clearer for you, since the key is simply `"a"`.

The other problem is, you get the selected Features by select.getFeatures(), which either returns a Feature or a Collection (see [API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select-Select.html#getFeatures)). The Feature does not have a `clear` method, but you can get the layer, and then remove the selected feature from it's source. This could look something like this:

```
var selectSource = select.getLayer(selectedFeature).getSource();
selectSource.removeFeature(selectedFeature);
```

this is, assuming you select a single feature, otherwise you could loop over the selected features.

Comment: I tried a new approach, but this never started working.
    select = new Select();
        map.addInteraction(select);
        select.on('select', function (e) {
            var count = e.target.getFeatures().getLength();
            alert(count);
            e.target.getFeatures().setMap(null);
            
        });

Comment: Basically i think you got the same problem there. getFeatures() returns an array of Features, the array does not have the method .setMap() (on another note, the features don't have this method either)

Comment: First, thank you for your help so far. How do i combine the select feature with vector.getSource().clear();

Comment: the .clear() method removes all the features from your source, is that really what you want? Otherwise, you should try the .removeFeature(Feature) Method of the source. I think you let the user select mutliple Features, so you should iterate over the feature collection (the selectedFeatures from your original question). A feature collection is basically just an array with features, you can just use a for loop and call the source.removeFeature-method like described above. 

unless you want to clear your whole source at once, i would not worry about the .clear() method.